# spring and hibernate integration class not found exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to spring and trying to get hibernate work with spring.I tried several hours to get this work how ever every time I get the following class not found exception.

```
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
> find class
> [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]
> for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource
> [mad/springnhibernate/model/spring.xml]; nested exception is
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
```

Followiing is my spring.xml file. Can you please explain me what is wrong with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mad.springnhibernate"/>
    <!-- Initialization for data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springnhibernate" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="mad.springnhibernate.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing jar file for `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`. You should include one of these jar. Find 
http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean